# Add time values in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, datetime, timedelta

I have a list of times that are in following format:

Hour:Minue:Second.Microseconds

File looks like this:

```
0:06:50.137529
0:08:55.439963
0:06:19.179093
0:07:16.680906
0:31:55.778010
0:16:56.940836
```

Is there a Python function or set of commands that will let me add all of these values together?

I initially "build" these values with the following code:

```
optimize_times = []
starting_time=(datetime.now())
ending_time=(datetime.now())
optimize_times.append(str(ending_time-starting_time))
```

Comment: Yes, `timedelta`, but it's not clear to me why you call `str()` on your results.

Comment: Without using the str function the value resulted in a timedelta function being output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datetime.timedelta` from the standard library:

```
from datetime import timedelta

L = ['0:06:50.137529', '0:08:55.439963', '0:06:19.179093',
     '0:07:16.680906', '0:31:55.778010', '0:16:56.940836']

def str_to_td(x):
    hrs, mins, sec_micro = x.split(':')
    secs, msecs = map(int, sec_micro.split('.'))
    return timedelta(hours=int(hrs), minutes=int(mins), seconds=secs, microseconds=msecs)

res = sum(map(str_to_td, L), timedelta())

# datetime.timedelta(0, 4694, 156337)
```

Note the output of this is a `timedelta` object. If this isn't the format your desire, you'll need to convert back to a string with additional logic.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.